# Modify inner content through Directive

Tags: angular, directive

I've stuck. I'm trying to add an extra sign after a text in a label.
I made a directive where I have the following code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

      this.el.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span style="color: red">*</span>');
  }
  @Input('myDirective') myDirective: string;
}
```

and then in label tag I add this directive name this way:

```
<label myDirective>some text</label>
```

This directive should add this extra asterix after 'some text' text. But does't  work. The extra asterix sign is still being added before 'this text'. So I got 
'*some text'. 
I dont know how to achive this, could you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your code to occur once the view has been rendered.

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[myDirective]'
})
export class MyDirective{

  @Input('myDirective') myDirective: string; 

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.el.nativeElement.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<span style="color: red">*</span>');
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-angular-directive-to-modify-label-content